# IllegalMonitorStateException with ArrayList NotifyAll() Wait()

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, wait

I know there are many answers on this topic and I think I have read them all.
Most of the answers do not include the namespace they use, and compiling the code they suggest is virtually impossible.

I am using VS 2015 Comunity with Xamarin and this is an Android project.

My namespaces:

```
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Util;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Util;
```

My code:

```
public static int updateWait()    // Called by a thread.
{
    int value = 0;

     try
    {
        while (msgList.IsEmpty)
        {
            msgList.Wait();
        }
        value = (int)msgList.Get(0);
        msgList.Remove(0) ;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Debug("", "" + e);
    }
    return value;
}

public static void updateNotify()   // called by a service
{
    if (msgList.IsEmpty)
    {
        msgList.Add(1000);
    }
    try
    {
            msgList.NotifyAll();
    }
    catch ( Exception e)
    {
        Log.Debug("", "" + e);
    }
}
```

The above code works **correctly**, since the thread from an activity seems to be blocked until the service calls `updateNotify()`. The problem is `IllegalMonitorStateException` are generated for every call to `msgList.NotifyAll()`, which I am ignoring.
Since only one thread notifies, and only one waits, there are no synchronization issues - but the exceptions are worrying.

Comment: public static ArrayList msgList = new ArrayList();

Answer (score 0):

You can't call notify() on an object if the current thread does not own that object's monitor.
You should put it in synchronized block.

```
synchronized(msgList) {
  msgList.NotifyAll();
}
```

Comment: The word 'synchronized' is not recognized using the above namespaces. I could not find one that does allow it. Also I have tried [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] above the function name, and that does not make a difference either.

Comment: try this:
synchronized(msgList) {
        ...
}

Comment: I have tried this. As I said, I get a compilation error: "The name 'synchronized' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: public static ArrayList msgList = new ArrayList();
       private readonly static object syncLock = new object();
        public static void updateNotify()
        {
            if (msgList.IsEmpty)
            {
                msgList.Add(1000);
            }
            try
            {
                lock (syncLock)
                {
                    msgList.NotifyAll();
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug("", "" + e);
            }
        }
This compiles but the exception is still there.

Comment: The concept that msgList.NotifyAll() must be rapped somehow to prevent run time exception from NotifyAll() is wrong, since it is up to the application to make sure the statement is executed atomically

Comment: Also tried:  static readonly object _object = new object();  Monitor.Enter(_object); msgList.NotifyAll(); Monitor.Exit(_object); ... but this also produces an exception.

Comment: Filed a bug with Microsoft using the 'Send Feedback' button on the Visual Studio. Check you updates.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested, Try :

```
lock(msgList) { 
   msgList.NotifyAll();
}
```